# Python Selenium: Element Is Not Clickable At Point

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using the code below to click on the highlighted tab that you see on the attached screenshot with the corresponding HTML code. The tab is always visible on the bottom of the script so there is no need to scroll down to it.

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tab-button-settings")))
element.click()
```

The error that I get is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Message: unknown error: Element <a class="tab-button has-icon icon-only" href="#" role="tab" ng- 
reflect-tab="[object Object]" id="tab-button-settings" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-1" aria- 
selected="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (1440, 1017). Other element would receive the 
click: <div class="click-block click-block-enabled click-block-active"></div>
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

[image]

Comment: The div that is intercepting the click is labeled "click-block-enabled", so if you should be able to click that link at this point, you've found a bug in the site.  (possibly an invisible modal or something like that??)

Answer (score 3):

you can use action class to avoid above issue

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tab-button-settings"))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Comment: This gives me "move target out of bounds"

Answer (score 0):

Another way alternative to javascript is to use touch actions

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tab-button-settings")))

touchactions = TouchActions(driver)
touchactions.tap(element).perform()
```

Comment: I tried it, and here is the error: `Message: unknown error: Element <a class="tab-button has-icon icon-only" href="#" role="tab" ng-reflect-tab="[object Object]" id="tab-button-settings" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-1" aria-selected="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (1440, 1017). Other element would receive the click: <div class="click-block click-block-enabled click-block-active"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tab-button.has-icon.icon-only#tab-button-settings"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='tab-button has-icon icon-only' and @id='tab-button-settings']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

In case the `unknown error` still occurs you may have to induce *WebDriverWait* additionally for the `invisibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.click-block.click-block-enabled.click-block-active")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.tab-button.has-icon.icon-only#tab-button-settings"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='click-block click-block-enabled click-block-active']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='tab-button has-icon icon-only' and @id='tab-button-settings']"))).click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium Web Driver & Java. Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912203/selenium-web-driver-java-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-elem/44916498#44916498)
- [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)… Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741875/selenium-common-exceptions-elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-cl/57749551#57749551)

Comment: The CSS Selector approach throws this error: `Message: unknown error: Element <a class="tab-button has-icon icon-only" href="#" role="tab" ng-reflect-tab="[object Object]" id="tab-button-settings" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-1" aria-selected="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (480, 28). Other element would receive the click: <div class="click-block click-block-enabled click-block-active"></div>`

Comment: And the XPath approach throws this: `Message: unknown error: Element <a class="tab-button has-icon icon-only" href="#" role="tab" ng-reflect-tab="[object Object]" id="tab-button-settings" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-1" aria-selected="false">...</a> is not clickable at point (1440, 1017). Other element would receive the click: <div class="click-block click-block-enabled click-block-active"></div>`