# Cant click button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I was making a webscraper with selenium and bs4 to keep some shopping items' stock in track, there is a load more button I want to click which looks like this
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8KOI.png)
and here is the HTML code for it, the website is https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-us

HTML code of the button

[image: HTML code of the button]

Whenever I try to find the element with bs4 it works but it never works with

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("buy-link load-more-btn")
```

and I need it to click the button, can someone help me out

Am I was passing too many classes at once?

Answer (score 3):

`find_element_by_class_name` accepts only one class. You are passing multiple classes in it.

Try implementing it with one class only

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("load-more-btn").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a combination of the other two suggestions. If I understand Selenium correctly, it basically converts any find_element_* into a css selector, so having a space in the class name messes things up if you put both. This worked for me.

```py
# Removes the Accept Cookies Banner
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.green-box-btn").click()
# Performs the click you want
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.buy-link").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("buy-link load-more-btn").click()
```

Please add click() to the end.

Answer (score -1):

The <kbd>LOAD MORE</kbd> element is located at the bottom of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) so to click on it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` which will automatically scroll the element within the [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126078/how-does-selenium-click-on-elements-that-are-50-on-screen-and-50-not-on-screen/59130869#59130869) and invoke `click()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.buy-link.load-more-btn[value='LOAD MORE']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='buy-link load-more-btn' and @value='LOAD MORE']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```