# Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (657, 594). Other element would receive the click with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I was making a webscraper to get gpu stocks from https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-us to get my hands on a 30 series card, I am using python with bs4 and selenium for this.

I want to load more shopping items, on the website it has this [load more button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfL22.png). So I grabbed its class and made it so selenium clicks it:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("buy-link").click()
```

but it says that the element in non interactiable,  HTML for the button

[image: this]

The exact error it gives me is:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="extra_style buy-link" data-color="#76b900" data-secondary-color="#fff" style="visibility: visible; cursor: pointer;" data-mpn-code="NVGFT070">...</span> is not clickable at point (657, 594). Other element would receive the click: <div class="popBg" id="nv-buy-now-model" style="display: block;">...</div>
```

I don't know much HTML, how can I achieve clicking this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>LOAD MORE</kbd> element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to click on it you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-us")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#cookiePolicy-btn-close>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.buy-link.load-more-btn[value='LOAD MORE']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-us")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='cookiePolicy-btn-close']/span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='buy-link load-more-btn' and @value='LOAD MORE']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: LOADMORE]

Comment: Selenium thinks the element was clickable, that's why it attempted the click. The problem is that there was a DIV in the way. See the error message OP posted.

Comment: that doesnt work, i dont think its the wait time, I think the element itself is inclickable

Comment: @JeffC You are wrong, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) can't think, it's neither a human nor AI enabled robot. The element is a _Angular_ element. So the bottom line is first you have to understand how  angular based website specifically angular element behaves and then use Selenium accordingly.

Comment: @KrypticCoconut Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjanB still the same error :( `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="buy-link load-more-btn" type="button" value="LOAD MORE"> is not clickable at point (464, 871). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="filter-button-container">...</div>`

Comment: @KrypticCoconut Did you test copy pasting the same code I've posted?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, exactly the same

Comment: @KrypticCoconut I still can't believe that. `LOAD MORE` is quite above the intercepting element. Does xpath and Css both gives the same error?

Comment: "Selenium thinks..." is an example of an anthropomorphism. There's nothing magical about Angular elements... if the element wasn't ready to be clicked, it would have thrown a different error. That was my point here and on other of your answers where you've answered in the same way. A wait doesn't fix that... as you've seen and modified your answer now several times.

Comment: @KrypticCoconut Did you keep the browser in **maximized** mode while trying to click?

Comment: oh, if i maximize it works, sorry if I'm being annoying but why does it do that only when its maximized?

Comment: @KrypticCoconut Never mind, we are here to help the _annoying_ but innovative minds :) You need to _maximize_ the browser so the desired elements are hosted within the [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126078/how-does-selenium-click-on-elements-that-are-50-on-screen-and-50-not-on-screen/59130869#59130869)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are some 20 elements on that page that match your first locator, `.find_element_by_class_name("buy-link")`. In this case, if you make your locator more specific, you can isolate it down to just the "LOAD MORE" INPUT button.

Try this instead

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.buy-link").click()
```

It's generally a good practice to add a wait unless you are sure you won't ever need it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='CLOSE']")).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.buy-link")).click()
```

See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for more info and details.

Comment: i changed the class to`load-more-btn`, that didnt work so I tried yours and same error :\
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="buy-link load-more-btn" type="button" value="LOAD MORE"> is not clickable at point (464, 871). Other element would receive the click: <div class="messageContainer fontSmall">...</div>`

Comment: So the issue now is that when Selenium scrolls down to click the LOAD MORE button, the button ends up underneath the cookie banner that states, "This site uses cookies to store information on your computer. See our cookie policy for further details on how to block cookies." Once you click CLOSE on the banner, the button should be revealed and clickable. I've updated the code and it successfully runs on my machine.

Comment: @JeffC Wrong inception again. Read the error once again,  the element `<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="filter-button-container">...</div>` is different from the cookie banner element. Why don't you check the website once?

Comment: @DebanjanB `I've updated the code and it successfully runs on my machine.` You should slow down and actually read the question... it would have saved you having to update your answer several times. You should also slow down and read my comments on your answer because they pointed this out but you out of hand dismissed them as you always do. You should also slow down and actually read *my* answer and the comments below my answer because if you would have, you'd have already seen that I tried this code and it works on my machine. I can't account for someone else's machine settings, etc.

Comment: @DebanjanB Also, I think you mean "assumption", not "inception". [inception definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inception)

Comment: huh, im getting a ctor error 

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')  
driver.get("https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-us")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='CLOSE']")).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.buy-link")).click()
```


`__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: @KrypticCoconut What's the error message? `ctor` is a constructor.

Comment: the error was `__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` mentioned it in comment

Comment: Is it on the `wait` line or which line was it on?