# How to get values from ag-grid table using selenium java without scrolling the table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using selenium java and have to get values from an ag-grid table that dynamically loads values when we scroll top to bottom or left to right. As of now, we are using JavaScriptExecutor to scroll the table and get the values.

Is there any other effective approach that can be used for getting the values without scrolling the table?

Please find a sample ag-grid table below,
https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php

Answer (score 2):

There are two pottential alteranitives against the usage of [JavaScriptExecutor to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54689339/7429447) as follows:

- the first alternative would be to use the [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) with **ExpectedConditions** [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) which scrolls the WebElement within the [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) by default. As an example:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("birtviewer")));
  ```
- The other alternative would be to use the [`moveToElement​(WebElement target)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)) as follows:

  ```
  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("link"));
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(myElement).build().perform();
  ```