# How to automatically fill out text fields in Selenium-java automation project

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to create a selenium automation project to automate a login page of a website and I could not auto fill out the data in the email section. I have used intelij idea, selenium and firefox-geckodriver as well as used selenium-java-3.141.59 jar file.

When running the automation project the login page is automatically loading. But can't auto fill the username field

The code I used:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class testDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //setting driver properties
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Driver\\Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
        //navigate driver to the website(not mentioned the actual URL here)
        driver.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);}
            //Enter username
            WebElement username= driver.findElement(By.id("signInFormUsername"));
            username.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);}
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys("Christina");
            WebElement txtbx_username = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
            txtbx_username.click();
            txtbx_username.clear();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e);}*/
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I got:

```
1658413753579   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:56968
1658413754419   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "62365" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "--remote-allow-origins" "http://localhost:62365/" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\INTERV~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileaE9gCO"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1658413755965   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 4319
1658413756461   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jul 21, 2022 7:59:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input id="signInFormUsername" class="form-control inputField-customizable" name="username" type="text"> could not be scrolled into view
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-5LAN9CC', ip: '192.168.8.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [88684e90-9cc0-49ff-99d9-d979b161ef98, clickElement {id=3fb62dd1-b2a7-4e45-b81a-b23444de5bff}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 78.1.0, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200722151235, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.31.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 21620, moz:profile: C:\Users\Intervest\AppData\..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Element: [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (88684e90-9cc0-49ff-99d9-d979b161ef98)] -> id: signInFormUsername]
Session ID: 88684e90-9cc0-49ff-99d9-d979b161ef98
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
    at testDriver.main(testDriver.java:32)
```

This is the html element for username

```
<input id="signInFormUsername" name="username" type="text" class="form-control inputField-customizable" placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="none" required="">
```

Can someone please provide me a solution for this or, provide me a proper tutorial fore selenium-java automation with inteliJ and firefox browser

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element `(By.id("signInFormUsername")`

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input id="signInFormUsername" class="form-control inputField-customizable" name="username" type="text"> could not be scrolled into view
```

...implies that [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) wasn't within the [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) when click was invoked.

---

### Solution

To [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control.inputField-customizable[name='username'][placeholder='Username']"))).click();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control inputField-customizable' and @name='username'][placeholder='Username']"))).click();
  ```