# How to get Coordinates any point whenever I click on browser with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium python, and i want to get Coordinates whenever i click any point
this is my code, anybody help me, how to get result in python

```
result = driver.execute_script("""
    function clickHandler(e) {
        console.log(e)
        var clickCoordinates = e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY;
        console.log(clickCoordinates)
        return clickCoordinates
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
""")
print(result)
```

I want to print clickCoordinates whenever click event

Answer (score 0):

### MouseEvent clientX Property

The [clientX](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp) is a read-only property of the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) interface which provides the horizontal coordinate within the application's [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) at which the event occurred (instead of the coordinate within the page).

As an example to retrieve the clientX coordinate of the mouse pointer while the mouse pointer moves you can use:

```
let x = event.clientX;
```

---

### MouseEvent clientY Property

The [clientY](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clienty.asp) is a read-only property of the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) interface which provides the vertical coordinate within the application's [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) at which the event occurred (instead of the coordinate within the page).

As an example to retrieve the clientY coordinate of the mouse pointer while the mouse pointer moves you can use:

```
let y = event.clientY;
```

---

### This usecase

To print clickCoordinates whenever click event occurs you can use the following solution:

```
result = driver.execute_script("""
    function clickHandler(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.clientX)
    console.log(e.clientY)
    var clickCoordinates = e.clientX + ',' + e.clientY;
    console.log(clickCoordinates)
    return clickCoordinates
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
""")
print(result)
```

---

### References

Link to useful documentations:

- [MouseEvent clientX clientY Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_screenxy_clientxy)

Comment: thanks bro, but i want to see it in python => print(result) not working, and i want to print whenever clickHandler emit.